# Can't add (correct) item in array in jsonb column

Tags: postgresql-9.5

meta - column type **jsonb**

Json before update:

```
{
    "state": "order.cart_finalization",
    "comments": [{
        "first_item": "hello"
    }]
}
```

I need to add new item to array (comments).

New array item is:

```
{ "second_item": "hello2"}
```

I try this:

```
 UPDATE copy_shop_order SET meta = (
    CASE
        WHEN meta #>>'{comments}' IS NULL THEN jsonb_set(meta, '{comments}', '[{ "first_item": "hello"}]')
        ELSE meta #>'{comments}' || '{ "second_item": "hello2"}'
    END
) WHERE id = 100;
```

But result is:

```
[
    {
        "first_item": "hello"
    },
    {
        "second_item": "hello2"
    }
]
```

But I need this:

```
  {
    "state": "order.cart_finalization",
    "comments": [{
        "first_item": "hello"
    }, {
        "second_item": "hello2"
    }]
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `jsonb_set()`

```
update copy_shop_order 
  SET meta = case 
               when meta ? 'comments' then jsonb_set(meta, '{comments}', meta -> 'comments' || '{"second_item": "hello2"}')
               else jsonb_set(meta, '{comments}', '[{ "first_item": "hello"}]')
             end;
```